# Converting two lists into a list of tuples based on specific conditions

Tags: python

I have two lists of URLs.

The first list contains for example 4 Sitemaps:

```
u1 = ['www.sample.de/tx/sitemap',
      'www.sample.de/foto/sitemap',
      'www.sample.de/er/sitemap',
      'www.far.de/sitemap',
      ]
```

The second list contains the links which were indexed on the different Sitemaps(several thousand links):

```
u2 = ['www.sample.de/tx/xxx',
      'www.sample.de/tx/xxx',
      'www.sample.de/foto/xxx',
      'www.sample.de/foto/xxx',
      'www.sample.de/er/xxx',
      'www.sample.de/er/xxx',
      'www.far.de/xxx',
      'www.far.de/xxx',
      ]
```

Now I want to merge these two lists into one list of tuples. So I know which link came from which sitemap.

```
u3 = [('www.sample.de/tx/xxx', 'www.sample.de/tx/sitemap'),
      ('www.sample.de/tx/xxx', 'www.sample.de/tx/sitemap'),
      ('www.sample.de/foto/xxx', 'www.sample.de/foto/sitemap'),
      ('www.sample.de/foto/xxx', 'www.sample.de/foto/sitemap'),
      ('www.sample.de/er/xxx', 'www.sample.de/er/sitemap'),
      ('www.sample.de/er/xxx', 'www.sample.de/er/sitemap'),
      ('www.far.de/xxx', 'www.far.de/sitemap'),
      ('www.far.de/xxx, www.far.de/sitemap'),
      ]
```

I tried to merge them via an if condition but this didnt work.

How can I do this properly?

Comment: Your code is not valid Python. Each string needs to be in quotes. Also you are missing some commas. Please edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check for partial match by removing everything after last `/` in `u2` and take the string that contains it from `u1`

```
u3 = [(url2, url1) for url2 in u2 for url1 in u1 if url2.rsplit('/', 1)[0] in url1]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def merge(list1, list2): 

    merged_list = [(p1, p2) for idx1, p1 in enumerate(list1)  
    for idx2, p2 in enumerate(list2) if idx1 == idx2] 
    return merged_list 
if(condition):
    merge(u1,u2)
```

Make your lists syntax right in qoutes  as below and replace the condition in if with what you want to check for

```
u1 = ["www.sample.de/tx/sitemap",
      "www.sample.de/foto/sitemap",
      "www.sample.de/er/sitemap",
      "www.far.de/sitemap",
      ]
```

Answer (score 1):

This is one approach by converting `u1` to a dict for easy lookup.

```
u1 = ["www.sample.de/tx/sitemap",
      "www.sample.de/foto/sitemap",
      "www.sample.de/er/sitemap",
      "www.far.de/sitemap",
      ]

u2 = ["www.sample.de/tx/xxx",
      "www.sample.de/tx/xxx",
      "www.sample.de/foto/xxx",
      "www.sample.de/foto/xxx",
      "www.sample.de/er/xxx",
      "www.sample.de/er/xxx",
      "www.far.de/xxx",
      "www.far.de/xxx"
      ]

u1 = {i.replace("/sitemap", ""): i for i in u1}
result = [(i,u1.get("/".join(i.split("/", 2)[:2]), i)) for i in u2]

print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
[('www.sample.de/tx/xxx', 'www.sample.de/tx/sitemap'),
 ('www.sample.de/tx/xxx', 'www.sample.de/tx/sitemap'),
 ('www.sample.de/foto/xxx', 'www.sample.de/foto/sitemap'),
 ('www.sample.de/foto/xxx', 'www.sample.de/foto/sitemap'),
 ('www.sample.de/er/xxx', 'www.sample.de/er/sitemap'),
 ('www.sample.de/er/xxx', 'www.sample.de/er/sitemap'),
 ('www.far.de/xxx', 'www.far.de/xxx'),
 ('www.far.de/xxx', 'www.far.de/xxx')]
```